# Is there a difference between flexible quotes in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, quotes

I feel I should preemptively apologize because this seems like the type of question that's probably been asked before. I couldn't find an answer so I'm asking here.

I'm going through the RubyKoans and I'm at line:24 of `about_strings.rb` 
There's a test:

```
def test_use_flexible_quoting_to_handle_really_hard_cases
  a = %(flexible quotes can handle both ' and " characters)
  b = %!flexible quotes can handle both ' and " characters!
  c = %{flexible quotes can handle both ' and " characters}
  assert_equal true, a == b
  assert_equal true, a == c
end
```

So what exactly is the difference between a, b, and c. Why exactly do three ways of doing something exist? This seems illogical. I know Ruby is flexible but I don't think of it as illogical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at other languages and you'll see the same thing.

There are times we need to be able to define a wrapping character that is NOT in the string, and using `%` allows us to do that. This is a powerful, and very usable, way of avoiding "[leaning toothpick syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)".

Comment: New to programming. Never heard of "leaning toothpick syndrome" but know exactly what you mean. I like this answer because the premise of my entire question was wrong. This wasn't a ruby question so much as a general programming question. Thanks.

Comment: Correct, it's general programming. Look through any of the questions for languages here on SO, or follow mail-lists or IRC chats, and you'll see the same problem show up. And, yeah, it's maddening until you learn about defining your own delimiting characters to wrap the string. Not all languages solve the problem the same way, but it's something you'll see handled somehow.

Answer (score 12):

There's not three ways, there's... a lot of ways.  Any non-alphanumeric character that follows % is a valid delimiter.

```
%[this is a valid string]
%~this is a valid string~
%+this is a valid string+
```

etc.

Note that brackets-and-friends are a little special, ruby is smart enough to allow you to use pairs of them - or even nest balanced pairs inside, *a la*

```
%[this is a [valid] string]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby you have "flexible quotes" syntax which is as follow: `%[any non-word, non-whitespace character]String[opening character or closing bracket]`. So you can use almost any non-word and non-whitespace character as a delimeter.

Answer (score 0):

`%{..}`,`%!..!` etc are same as `%Q{}` construct, that means string interpolation will happen. Be careful that the construct `%{..}`,`%!..!` are not `%q{..}`.

```
>> x = 5
=> 5
>> %q[#{x}] # interpolation will not happen
=> "\#{x}"
>> %[#{x}] # interpolation will happen
=> "5"
>> %Q[#{x}] # interpolation will happen
=> "5"
>>
```

[*The % Notation*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation)

There is also a *Perl-inspired way* to quote strings: by using % (percent character) and specifying a delimiting character, for example:

```
%{78% of statistics are "made up" on the spot}
# => "78% of statistics are \"made up\" on the spot"
```

Any *single non-alpha-numeric character* can be used as the delimiter, `%[including these]`, `%?or these?`, `%~or even these things~`. By using this notation, the usual string delimiters `"` and `'` can appear in the string *unescaped*, **but of course the new delimiter you've chosen does need to be escaped**. However, if you use `%(parentheses)`, `%[square brackets]`, `%{curly brackets}` or `%<pointy brackets>` as delimiters then those same delimiters can appear *unescaped* in the string as long as they are in balanced pairs:

```
%(string (syntax) is pretty flexible)
# => "string (syntax) is pretty flexible"
```